# How do I know what day it is in Pokemon Black & White?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I am playing Pokemon White and I noticed there are decent amount of events that occur only on specific days. Now my problem is that I have no idea which day is it in-game at any time and I don't want to visit those event places every few minutes to check am I currently in that day required for event.

I tried going through all menus in the game and just couldn't find anything, and I Googled a lot and couldn't find an answer.

Does anyone know is there a way to check which day is it in Pokemon White (and Black)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The day in-game is the same as the current real-world day of the week, assuming your system clock is set properly on your DS.

Comment: Damn i really hoped that is not the case,now I'll have to wait for ages (read:days) IRL before i can do some events and that just sucks.Thanks.

Comment: Just change the ds system date to your convenience. Unlike heartgold, where changing the system date could affect the berry growth rate as well as the Pokewalker, there is no penalty for repeatedly changing the time in b/w. I do it all the time for Rnging.

Comment: Yeah already figured that out and did it to do some events.Thanks anyway xD

Answer (score -1):

As the other comment says your in-game day is the same as your real life day. This [article](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/dailyevent.shtml) it lists the events by day.

Comment: That is great information, and you should consider incorporating some of it into your answer. Links could go dead, and it also grabs the eye more than a short answer with a link.